# Find the intersection points of two asymptotic functions

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I'm trying hard to find the intersection points of two asymptotic functions, in order to figure out at what exactly n coordinates, one function surpasses another.

$y(n)=8n^2$

$g(n)=64n\lg n$

to find the intersection points, I transform them into the following equation:

$8n^2=64n\lg n$

both side divided by $8n$, as suggested by Tanner, then we have:

$n=8\lg n$

But I still have no idea how to solve it.

ps: $lg$ is 2 base.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You could divide both sides of the equation by $8n$ (assuming $n\ne0$)

Comment: Is $\lg x$ supposed to be $\lg n$?

Comment: @Ben Tes, I'll fix it.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Still don't know how to solve it, more hints?

Comment: now that you changed $x$ to $n$, you may need the [Lambert W-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Comment: One approach (not sure if correct so not posting as answer). Starting from 

$$n=8\lg n$$

rewrite (assuming $n > 0$)

$$n=8\lg n\implies n=\frac{8\log (n)}{\log (2)}\implies \frac{n}{\log (n)} = \frac{8}{\log(2)}$$

then since $e^{\log n}=n$ we have

$$\frac{e^{\log n}}{\log (n)} = \frac{8}{\log(2)}$$

where you can apply the Lambert W function to conclude

$$\frac{1}{\log{n}}=W(-\frac{\log 2}{8}) \implies \log n = \frac{1}{W(-\frac{\log 2}{8})}\implies n = e^{-W(-\frac{\log 2}{8})}$$